# How to migrate custom fields to Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I'm trying to set up my migration mapping to transfer over some custom fields that were created by installed modules, but I'm unsure how to define that in `map.xml`

For example, I have the field `sales_flat_order`.`onestepcheckout_customercomment` which I'd like to move to `sales_order`.`onestepcheckout_customercomment`. So I include the following in my `map.xml`:

```
    <move>
        <field>sales_flat_order.onestepcheckout_customercomment</field>
        <to>sales_order.onestepcheckout_customercomment</to>
    </move>
```

But the migration tool doesn't know the destination field `sales_order.onestepcheckout_customercomment` and so fails to map it.

My guess is there is some `<transform>` block I should be using, but I can't find any documentation detailing the different transform handlers.

Comment: you need to create such column into magento 2 db manually or using some script.

Answer (score 6):

To migrate custom fields to Magento 2, the custom field column must map to an existing Magento 2 table column. If the custom field column does not already exist in the Magento 2 table then you can't map the custom field into Magento 2.

Here's an example (this is from the default Magento 2 map file). In the `cms_page` table from Magento 1, the column `root_template` exists, but that column is not available in the Magento 2 `cms_page` table. Thus, custom field mapping is done using the tags below. Here the custom field `root_template` is mapped onto `page_layout` so that all values of `root_template` transfer to the `page_layout` field of the `cms_page` Magento 2 table.

```
<move>
    <field>cms_page.root_template</field>
    <to>cms_page.page_layout</to>
</move>
```

In your case, `onestepcheckout_customercomment` is a custom field that is not available in the default `sales_flat_order` table, so you can only map that field onto Magento 2 if you have created a new field inside the Magento 2 `sales_order` table. Otherwise you can't do the mapping.

Your mapping tag is in the right direction, but mapping is not possible because the `sales_order` table in Magento 2 doesn't contain the `onestepcheckout_customercomment` field.

Your code inside `map.xml`

```
<move>
        <field>sales_flat_order.onestepcheckout_customercomment</field>
        <to>sales_order.onestepcheckout_customercomment</to>
</move>
```

would work if the `sales_order` table had the `onestepcheckout_customercomment` field. You don't need a transform tag for basic field mapping.

Thanks.

Comment: Does that mean I need to manually update the table structure to add the new field?  Is there no method for add custom fields to existing tables through the migration tool?

Comment: There are not custom tool for migrate custom field using migration tool. you have to add custom field using Setup/Upgradeschema file or manually add field to table.

Answer (score 4):

You should create (preferably by schema setup script) columns in the relevant table where you want the custom fields to be in.

The migration tool doesn't create new columns.