# Magento 2. Migration. Map customer attribute

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, data-migration

Can a customer_attribute be mapped during a M1 -> M2 data migration, if so can anyone provide any clues on how to do that?

e.g M1 attribute tel => M2 attribute telephone

Comment: Have you created the necessary mapping files as per http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html#migration-config?

Comment: @LiamMcArthur Devodocs does not provide a way to map one attribute to another. At least I could not find it in the docs. It provides ways to map columns but attributes are EAV therefor rows. What I'm looking is a semantic mapping rather than a schematic one.

Comment: This link may help you. Please check

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102232/how-to-migrate-custom-fields-to-magento2

Comment: @Vulpea, telephone is customer address attribute not customer attribute

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala :) You are missing the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not direct way to map an attribute with a given `attribute_code` from Magento 1 to another with another `attribute_code` from Magento 2.

If both attributes have the same `attribute_code` an update is made.

**What I've tried:**

The data-migration-tool offers a transform handler `\Migration\Handler\Convert` that converts the value of one column for all rows or rows that meet a condition on value:value pair

e.g

```
<transform>
        <field>catalog_category_entity_varchar.value</field>
        <handler class="\Migration\Handler\ConvertEavValue">
                    <param name="map" value="[one_column:1column]"/>
                    <param name="attributeCode" value="page_layout"/>
        </handler>
 </transform>
```

This will transform all rows that have the value `one_column` to `1column` where `attribute_code` is `page_layout` for the `catalog_category_entity_varchar.value column`

The example provided usses `\Migration\Handler\ConvertEavValue` but the logic is the same for `\Migration\Handler\Convert`

This is **NOT** possbile for the `attribute_code` column due the fact that the migration process relies heavily on the attribute_code values. Changing the `attribute_code` value during migration will result in unwanted results. I deduced this from the several checks they make along the way to see if `attribute_code` values stay the same.

**What I ended up doing:**

Ran a post-migration script that updates the list of `attribute_codes` that I wanted to change.

Comment: where can i keep this code for customer custom attribute?