# Manage entity_id in data migration from M1 to M2

Tags: magento2, magento-1, migration, data-migration

We are planning to migrate data from M1 to M2 and for that we are planning to write custom script because there are lot of customisation done on M1.

We have lot of stores available in M1, We are planning store wise migration, so for that we have a doubts.

- In sales orders table there is field available entity_id that is manage with other third party systems.

for this can anyone suggest us better solution that can be implemented?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on data migration with the Magento default tool,
https://meetanshi.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

for migration custom fields you need to write rules,
[How to migrate custom fields to Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102232/how-to-migrate-custom-fields-to-magento2)

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do you have any idea to manage entity_id from M1 to M2?

Comment: The suggested tool just keep the same entity_id when migrating tables. In this way it will keep tables consistency and relations on M2

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, I suggest you to create a test environment and try a migration